# Button pop-up bounce animation like What's App

Tags: java, android, kotlin, animation, button

I'm trying to make a list of buttons bounce when a view gets visible. But I cannot get the desired result, it doesn't look similar at all.

I tried it with a bounce interpolator and an overshoot interpolator (used on a scale animation), but as said, it doesn't look similar to the desired result.

---

This is a gif of the desired result, it's from What's App. It's not about the circular reveal, it's only about that bouncing pop-up animation they used on the buttons (document, camera, gallery, audio, ... buttons).

[image]